# Java EE - cannot see another entities in responses while doing GET request

Tags: java, jpa, h2

I am learning Java EE and I cannot figure out why I am not able to see another entities in GET responses. I am using H2 database.

I want to see list of players in GET club response and club info in GET player response but cannot see any.

Here are some code samples:

**Player's class**

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Player implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String nationality;
    private String position;
    private Club club;
    private int club_id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

        //getters and setters

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "club_id")
    @Transient
    public Club getClub()
    {
        return club;
    }
}
```

**Club's class**

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Club implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private Date foundationDate;
    private String trainer;
    private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

        //getters and setters

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @Transient
    public List<Player> getPlayers(){
        return players;
    }
}
```

I am also doing something like this in ClubEJB.java:

```
public List<Club> get() {
    Query q = manager.createQuery("select c from Club c");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Club> list = q.getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

and something like this in PlayerEJB.java

```
public void create(Player player) {
    System.out.println("Creating player!");
    Club club = manager.find(Club.class, player.getClub_id());
    club.getPlayers().add(player);
    manager.persist(player);
}
```

[cannot see any player despite adding one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uwBt.png)